# Adding row in tree list after every child node

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xtratreelist, treelist

I  m using devexpress tools and while using treelist i want to apply this.
I want to add a row after every child node which could take text values and the size of the row should be stretched to the full width.How can i do this..?[image: This image will give u an idea of what i m asking for . I want a row which could take text values after every childnode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Preview Section. This feature is well described in the documentation: [Preview Section](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1074)

The preview text can be supplied via event or bound to the datasource field. If the preview text is empty, the preview section is not painted. This behavior allows you to have the preview section only for specific nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot .It seems to be correct .I have tried this with the help of documentation but was not able to get the required output.I don't y something is wrong and i m not able to set this TreeListOptionsView.ShowPreview = true . Please help me if u can. It would be a great relief.

Comment: The ShowPreview is an instance property. You can configure this option for a particular TreeList instance using the code like follows: this.TreeList.OptionsView.ShowPreview = true;